# Load new pages via Ajax without refreshing the whole nav bar Django

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

I'm new to Django and I'm building my own website. I have written a `base.html` page that contains the main body, CSS, js, fonts, and the navbar that all the pages of my site will have. The navbar is on another HTML file, `navbar.html`

Now, as soon as the CSS/js/fonts/navbar included in the `base.html` will be loaded on every page and won't change, is there a way with Ajax to load only the actual content of the page that change seamless without seeing the whole page refresh?

For instance, the part of the page that visually changes everytime is inside a `<section class="home"></section>` tag

Comment: Do you want to do something like a Single Page Application (SPA)?

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby nope, I have multiple pages for application but the navbar doesn't change and it is quite bad to see it blink everytime a page is loaded

Answer (score 1):

When using JQuery, it is quite simple:

```
<script>
   function load_page(url) {
      $.ajax({
         url: url,
         success: function (data) {
            $('#nav_id').html('');
            data.nav_items.forEach(item => {
               $('#nav_id').append($('<div>').onclick(load_page(item.url)).text(item.title));
            }
         },
         error: function () {
            alert('Could not load data');
         }
      });
   }
</script>
```

And in your url you can define this as /nav/str:slug/ which leads to a view like this:

```
def nav_ajax(request, slug):
   if slug == 'a':
       return JsonResponse({
          'navitem1': {
              'title': 'A',
              'url': reverse('your_nav_url_name', kwargs={'slug':'a'}),
       },
       # other menu items
       )
   else:
      return JsonResponse({}) # default menu items
```

Comment: are you sure the code is correct? I got a unresolved function error for `load_page`

Comment: See edit, I forgot to add function keyword before the load_page function

Comment: Just to be clear, is `navitem1` a placeholder or do I need to change with something on my code? And, do I need to create a `return JsonResponse` for every item on my nav bar with the right URL that they're pointing to?